# Settimeout is running fast

Tags: javascript

I have a while loop calling a function every second:

```
function draw (){
        console.log(then-now)
    };
var i = 0
while(i < 100){
    setTimeout(draw,1000)
    i++;
};
```

But this is not waiting a second between each call to draw, it is calling it 100 times at once.

Comment: That's how `while` statements work; they run their code multiple times. Your code is creating 100 timeouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`setInterval`](http://jsfiddle.net/L7wED/):

```
function draw (){
    console.log(then-now)
    i++;
    if (i >= 100) clearInterval(interval);
};
var i = 0
var interval = setInterval(draw, 100);
```

If you wanted to use [`setTimeout`](http://jsfiddle.net/L7wED/1/), you'd have to set the next iteration from inside the `draw` function itself.

```
function draw (){
    console.log(then-now)
    i++;
    if (i < 100) setTimeout(draw, 100);
};
var i = 0;
setTimeout(draw, 100);
```

This is because `setTimeout` is asynchronous, so your while loop doesn't pause -- it keeps going, launching each instance of `draw` almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want

```
while(i < 100){
    i++;
    setTimeout(draw, i*1000);
};
```

Notice that [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) schedules a task for the future, but does not wait - it returns immediately, making your code asynchronous.

However, it is not good practise to queue 100 tasks at once. Better:

```
var i = 0;
function draw (){
    console.log(then-now)
    if (i<100) {
        i++;
        setTimeout(draw, 1000); // maybe adjusted to actual time
    }
};
draw();
```

Comment: I don't think that creating 100 timeouts at once is a good approach. I'd have the callback function initiate subsequent timeouts.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I had extended my answer with exactly that before you posted your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(draw, 1000);
```

should be:

```
setTimeout(draw, 1000 * (i + 1));
```

So that each timeout created is `1s` longer.

The `i + 1` is so that the first timeout is `1000`, rather than `0`, as `i` starts at `0`.